# How do you make a blank script on Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I cannot seem to find out how.

Answer (score 2):

In the insert menu of roblox studio, click insert and find the script object and select ok. Then to modify it, you double click on the object in the explorer window. The first link is to set up the studio correctly, and the second is a basic introduction to scripting.

http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Studio

[http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Absolute_beginner's_guide_to_scripting](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Absolute_beginner%27s_guide_to_scripting)

Answer (score 2):

`Insert > Object > Script`

Double click the script in the `Workspace` then press `CTRL + A` then `BACKSPACE` and it will clear the script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a blank script, then insert a script, and remove whats inside it

Answer (score 0):

1. Open tools
2. Click the insert dropdown menu
3. Click object
4. Click script